# ApacheFOP - Error "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found in java.lang.ClassLoader$1{urls=[], parent=null}"

Tags: java, .net, apache, apache-fop, altova

I am working on a project that uses a .NET wrapper on Altova Stylevision/ Apache FOP to create a PDF using a WCF web service.

It worked under .net 3.5, but upgrading to .net 4, I get the following error:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException : http://xml.org/sax/handlers/LexicalHandler

Stacktrace : at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(Source source, Result outputTarget) at... line of own .net code.

source: fop-0.93

There was no inner exception, so I tried turning on as much debugging capability as possible. The only extra info was in the stack trace:

"{"org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found in java.lang.ClassLoader$1{urls=[], parent=null}"}"

Does anyone know what the problem is/ how to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit mickey mouse, but I lost hours trying to get this to work, so thought I'd write something here in case it helps anyone else.

For this specific error, I just left it for a few hours, came back and it worked. Maybe it was a caching issue, or wrapper caching issue.

Not fully sure why, but it's now resolved.